# Many Laravel installations on Wamp

Tags: apache, wampserver, laravel

So, lately I've been working on some projects, using Laravel is great, but I can't figure out how to properly set up the VirtualHost, because everytime I do, I can only visit the current project I am working on, other links giving me errors.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/JonSnow/Sites/MySite/public
    ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I have this on the end in my httpd.conf, how can I properly change it to allow me to visit localhost/ and other project installations?

Current:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/www
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/game/public
    ServerName localhost/game
</VirtualHost>
```

Now... I just want localhost to be my ordinary and simply point localhost/game to the public folder.

Comment: have you put `mysite.dev` in your hosts file? (to resolve the name to your machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pull it off with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /Users/JonSnow/Sites
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

as long as `NameVirtualHost *:80` is added somewhere in your `httpd.conf` file.

That works for me anyhow :)

Comment: Just as an addendum to this, the first virtualhost you set up becomes your default, so set this one up first, then set up additional ones after it. This could be why you're experiencing problems?

Comment: So, with NameVirtualHost I would be able to add another project, (of course adding another virtuahost) like I point a servername to localhost/projectone and one to localhost/projecttwo

Comment: Yep, so sub-folders of your server's document root (should be setup somewhere else in the httpd.conf file) will be accessible through localhost/project1 and localhost/project2, but you could pint a virtualhost to project2 for example, and it'll work at `project2.local`, or whatever you setup the servername to be.

Comment: Just make sure that `NameVirtualHost *:80` is declared *once*, and is above your virtualhost declarations - i've done both wrong before and the entire server doesn't start sometimes.

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/game/public
    ServerName localhost/game
</VirtualHost>


Points the laravel installation to localhost not localhost/game :/

Comment: Just set the servername to be `localhost`, not `localhost/game`, that will automatically allow directories underneath your site root to be accessed by going to `localhost/project1` etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your httpd.conf file (which you can access via the Wamp config menu)

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName mysite.dev
    DocumentRoot "e:/www/mysite/public"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName gamesite.dev
    DocumentRoot "e:/www/gamesite/public"
</VirtualHost>

// repeat for each site you want to work on
```

Then you ALSO need to edit a file called "`hosts`" (no extension - just "`hosts`") - you can find it in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`. Inside that file, it might be empty, or you might already have some stuff in there. Just put these two lines at the very very very top of the file (i.e. line 1)

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.dev
127.0.0.1 gamesite.dev

// repeat for each site you are working on
```

Now save, restart your computer, and then it will work.